Just today, every edit comment I try to make is "reserved for system use"
I'm trying to submit a basic edit, but no matter what I type, the website says "Comment reserved for system use. Please use an appropriate comment."
I've never had problems with edit messages like "fixed punctuation, typo" before until now. What is going on?

Closing this the other way around would be much more sensible. At least this question says the error occurs on SO with a regular edit message. The other question says this occurs on astronomy SE with an astronomy-specific edit message.
